# How can I make my JList selectable by the user?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, joptionpane

I'm messing around creating a program that pulls movie information from IMDB's top 250 rated movies (Movie, Year, Rating) using `JSoup`. I've managed to figure out how to print this list within a `JScrollPane`. I've also created a separate `ArrayList` that contains the links to the page of each movie. What I want to do is make each item in the JList selectable so that if the user left-clicks on a movie it will take you to the URL. How can I go about this?

```
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class MovieList {
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> movieInfo;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> movieInfo = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> linkInfo = new ArrayList<>();
        String imdb = "http://www.imdb.com/chart/top?ref_=nv_mv_250_6";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(imdb).get();
        Elements title = doc.select("td.titleColumn");
        Elements year = doc.select("span.secondaryInfo");
        Elements rating = doc.select("td.ratingColumn.imdbRating");
        Elements link = doc.select("td.titleColumn a");


        for(Element linkList: link){
            linkInfo.add(linkList.attr("abs:href"));
        }

        int i=0;
        for(Element movieList: title){
            ArrayList<String> movie = new ArrayList<>();
            i++;
            movie.add(i+": "+movieList.getElementsByTag("a").text());
            movieInfo.add(movie);
        }
        int x=0;
        for(Element yearList: year){
            movieInfo.get(x).add(1,yearList.getElementsByTag("span").text());
            x++;
        }
        int y=0;
        for(Element ratingList: rating){
            movieInfo.get(y).add(2,"Rating: "+ratingList.getElementsByTag("strong").text());
            y++;
        }

        DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
        for(ArrayList<String> j: movieInfo){
            listModel.addElement(j.toString()+"\n");
        }

        JList<String> jList = new JList<>(listModel);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jList);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(575,1080));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, scrollPane);


    }

}
```

Comment: `pulls movie information from IMDB's top 250 rated movies (Movie, Year, Rating)` - maybe you should be using a JTable instead of a JList to store the information. Read the section from the Swig tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) . for more information.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a read.

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to do is make each item in the JList selectable so that if the user left-clicks on a movie it will take you to the URL

Start with [How to use list selection listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) to [Selecting items in a list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#selection) to see how you can detect selection changes

> it will take you to the URL

See [How to Integrate with the Desktop Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html) to see how you can open the URL in the user's browser